# How to create Android Emulator in Eclipse

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, android-emulator, kvm

[image] 
I am trying to create emulator in linux OS(Processor is Intel core 2 Duo),but it shows that Kvm is required to create emulator.The problem is that my system does not support Kvm,is there any other method for the successful creation of emulator?Any answer will be highly appreciable..
Advance Thanks...

Comment: whether your Ubuntu is 32-bit or 64-bit

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu

Comment: @Sultan my ubuntu is 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

Hello i recomend Genymotion the fastest emulator http://techapple.net/2014/07/tutorial-installsetup-genymotion-android-emulator-linux-ubuntulinuxmintfedoraarchlinux/ and  http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/06/install-genymotion-in-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: i tried to add with eclipse(genymotion) as specified in https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download but i cannot succesfully complete it there is some errors occurs,also downloaded that genymotion-eclipse-plugin.jar but no jar file inside that.